# How to recycle unreachable objects for future using in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, recycle

I'm using `gsll` with `antik` to do some scientific calculations, and I found that `antik` does not reuse unreachable objects and always allocates new ones, which makes my program slow.

For example, there's a function called `lu-invert` in `gsll`, which calculates the inversion of a given matrix, and an optional destination object can be specified. If I specify a destination object, `lu-invert` will store the results into that object. Otherwise, `lu-invert` will allocate a new object to store the results.

I compared the time consumption of the two cases, and the former is much faster than the latter. However, it's very inconvenient to always specify destination objects for those functions.

I'm wondering whether there is a way that unreachable objects can be automatically recycled and reused instead of always allocating new ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A technique to reuse discarded objects instead of having the garbage collector deal with them are [Resources](http://common-lisp.net/project/bknr/static/lmman/resour.xml).  A Common Lisp version of Resources is available in [Peter Norvig's auxfns.lisp](http://norvig.com/paip/auxfns.lisp).

Comment: I'd be cautious about using resources. In my (distant past) experience (not with GSLL), it took an enormous size allocation of memory to be faster than discarding and garbage collecting all the time. It seems like resources should always be a plus, but there is some overhead and modern gc is very efficient.